# Install multiple MySQL clusters on same machine - CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos

I am new to MySQL and i'm trying to create multiple mysql clusters on the same host with different port number. I know that default port is 3306 so I tried to configure the my.cnf to something like this:

```
[mysqld2]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
port=3307
```

and then run mysql -P 3307 but that doesn't work. I don't know how to start the cluster on this port.
Please send help :)

Edit:

So i found out I need to create another configuration file and made it to here:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql2
chmod --reference /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql2
chown --reference /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql2
cp -p /etc/my.cnf /etc/my2.cnf
vi /etc/my2.cnf
--------------------------------------
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock
port=3337

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
--------------------------------------



mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
```

Now I have a new data directory set and a configuration file, problem is I don't know how to start this specific cluster(with this configuration file I made)

Edit2:

Now when I run mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf i get this error:

```
[root@pg66 ~]# mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf
2020-12-31T09:50:08.821792Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 28085
2020-12-31T09:50:08.838198Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-31T09:50:09.551655Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-31T09:50:10.670160Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2020-12-31T09:50:10.670328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of bind-address: '*' port: 33060 failed, `bind()` failed with error: Address already in use (98). Do you already have another mysqld server running with Mysqlx ?'
2020-12-31T09:50:10.670440Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013597] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Value '*' set to `Mysqlx_bind_address`, X Plugin can't bind to it. Skipping this value.'
2020-12-31T09:50:10.670592Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, another process with PID 26783 is using UNIX socket file'
2020-12-31T09:50:11.007743Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-31T09:50:11.007904Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-12-31T09:50:11.063486Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock'  port: 3337  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
^C^C^[[A^C
```

Comment: I think you have to create another `my.cnf` config file (ex: my2.cnf) with the configuration of your second instance. By the way, I think you have to use `[mysqld]` instead of `[mysqld2]`

Comment: Yeah, I just found it out. edited my question. still need to figure out how to start the cluster

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch mysql with your config file.
`mysqld_safe – -defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf` && `mysqld_safe – -defaults-file=/etc/my1.cnf`

More infos: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: I am using mysql  Ver 8.0.22 , whenever I run mysqld_safe I get command not found.

Comment: you are one Linux or Windows ? If you are on Linux, you can try `locate mysqld_safe` or use `mysqld` instead of `mysqld_safe`.

Comment: im on centos 7, cannot find the mysqld_safe. when I run with mysqld instead I get many errors.

Comment: i'll write the error in my main question so it be easier to see.

Comment: by the way, I am trying to have 2 servers running. one on the default port 3306 with my.cnf and another one on port 3337.